# If a prime number is reversed, and then appended to itself, why is the result always a composite number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, pattern-recognition

$2 \Rightarrow 22$ which is a composite number.

$37 \Rightarrow 3773$ which is a composite number.

$523 \Rightarrow 523325$ which is a composite number.

$8123 \Rightarrow 81233218$ which is a composite number.

If you take any prime, reverse it, and append it to itself, the result always seems to be a composite number. I have checked this for $2 \leq n \leq 999999$.

Is there a reason for this, or is it simply a coincidence?

Comment: None of your examples seem to show what you mean by "reversing the number". Your examples are all divisible by 11. Can you elaborate a bit more with maybe 2-digit examples of higher?

Comment: I think he means reversing the digits

Comment: It works for any number, not just primes, and the result divisible by $11$.

Comment: @Seth: Sure, me too. But I see no specification of that anyway ...

Comment: @coffeemath Every number except 1 ;-)

Comment: @Seth It's *still* divisible by $11$, though. It just happens to be 11.

Comment: @Taylor If you'd like to read more about these numbers, they're called [palindromes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number).

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Okay, thank you. I have, in fact, heard of palindromes before, such as in the date 01/11/10, where, if it is reversed, it stays the same. I suppose this is the same as when you take the name 'Hannah', for example, and reverse it, which returns 'Hannah' again.

Comment: 131 is a palindrome too, but it's not divisible by 11. The argument for divisibility by 11 only works if the number of digits is even.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: Any number appended in reverse to itself will necessarily have an even number of digits.

Comment: @FooBarrigno Yes, of course. But someone might well assume the result holds for arbitrary palindromes, and I wanted to nip this generalization in the bud.

Comment: It's lucky 1 isn't prime or it would be false. Otherwise for the reasons said: that the number is divisible by 11

Comment: A good follow up to this would be whether it (or anything like it) works in non-base 10 number systems.

Comment: @jpmc26 I imagine it would still hold but just be divisible by 11 in whatever base it was you chose.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As [John's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1093523) notes, every [palindromic number](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number) with an even number of digits is divisible by $11$, because the alternating sum of its digits is zero (and thus a multiple of $11$).

For example, for $81233218$, we have: $$8-1+2-3+3-2+1-8 = 0,$$ and so $81233218$ is divisible by $11$.

The *reason* why this [divisibility rule](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule) works is most easily seen using a bit of [modular arithmetic](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Specifically, by definition, two numbers $a$ and $b$ are equivalent modulo $m$ (which we write as $a \equiv b \pmod m$) if and only if their difference $a-b$ is divisible by $m$.  Thus, in particular, a number $n$ is divisible by $m$ if and only if $n \equiv 0 \pmod m$.

Now, the reason this definition is handy is because we can "do arithmetic under the modulus $m$": in particular, if $a \equiv a' \pmod m$ and $b \equiv b' \pmod m$, then $a+b \equiv a'+b' \pmod m$ and $ab \equiv a'b' \pmod m$.  Thus, if we're only interested in the result of a calculation modulo some number $m$ (like, say, if we just want to know whether $n \equiv 0 \pmod{11}$ for some number $n$), and the calculation only involves operations that work equivalently "under the modulus" (such as addition and multiplication, and any combination thereof), then we can freely add or subtract multiples of $m$ from any intermediate values to make them more convenient (which often means "closer to zero").

In particular, from the definition it clearly follows that: $$10 \equiv -1 \pmod{11},$$ since $10 - (-1) = 10 + 1 = 11$.  We also know that the numerical value of [a base-$10$ number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) is mathematically obtained by multiplying its lowest digit with $1$, the second digit with $10$, the third digit with $10^2 = 100$, etc., and adding the results together.  For example: $$81233218 = 10^7 \cdot 8 + 10^6 \cdot 1 + 10^5 \cdot 2 + 10^4 \cdot 3 + 10^3 \cdot 3 + 10^2 \cdot 2 + 10 \cdot 1 + 8.$$

But since $10 \equiv -1 \pmod{11}$, if we only want to calculate the value of the number modulo $11$, we can replace $10$ with $-1$ in this calculation!  Thus: $$81233218 \equiv (-1)^7 \cdot 8 + (-1)^6 \cdot 1 + (-1)^5 \cdot 2 + (-1)^4 \cdot 3 + (-1)^3 \cdot 3 + (-1)^2 \cdot 2 + (-1) \cdot 1 + 8 \pmod{11}.$$

And, of course, we can easily see that the powers of $-1$ simply alternate between $-1$ and $1$, so this expression simplifies down to: $$81233218 \equiv -8 + 1 -2 + 3 - 3 + 2 - 1 + 8 = 0 \pmod{11}.$$

(Ps. The same trick also works in bases other than $10$, showing that any number palindromic in base $b$, with an even number of base-$b$ digits, is necessarily divisible by $b+1 = 11_b$.)

Comment: Beautifully explained.

Comment: Thanks, @John. Ps. Enjoy your new gold badge! :)

Comment: Sometimes the procedure gives a semiprime of the form $11$ times a prime (which is the closest to a prime we can hope for). This happens for `2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 14, 16, 19, 31, 32, 34, 38, 71, 74, 79, 91, 92, 94, 100, ...`. If you want to start with a prime only, it is `2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 19, 31, 71, 79, ...`. These sequences do not appear in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/).

Answer (score 55):

All numbers of this kind are divisible by $11$.

Consider prime $\mathit{abcdefg}$ where each letter is a digit.

The number $\mathit{gfedcbaabcdefg}$ is divisible by $11$ because the [alternating sum of digits is always zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule#Divisibility_rules_for_numbers_1.E2.80.9320):

$$g - f + e - d + c - b + a - a + b - c + d - e + f - g = 0.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @Taylor Alternatively because $10^{2n}+1=(10+1)\cdot(10^{2n-1}-10^{2n-2}+\dots (-1)^{r-1}10^{2n-r} \dots +1)$ which shows where the rule comes from.

Comment: I should learn to refresh the page before clicking on "Post your answer"...

Comment: @zarathustra It is fine! Thank you very much for your answer, also. In fact, I think it is great that you have given an alternate answer to the question!

Comment: @Taylor, you are very welcome. Glad this could help!

Comment: The same link had "If the number of digits is even, add the first and subtract the last digit from the rest." This makes it super easy, since the first and last digits will be the same, and you could do this operation until you exhausted all digits.

Comment: BTW you can use a similar trick to [extract perfect three-digit cube roots in your head](http://thinkinghard.com/blog/CubeRoots.html).

Answer (score 27):

As has been pointed out in the comments, this is not a special property of the primes.  Rather it's true that whenever you reverse a number and append the result to itself, the result is always divisible by 11.

To see why this is true, consider the number $A = 10^{n-1} a_{n-1} + 10^{n-2} a_{n-2} + \cdots + 10^0 a_0$, where $a_0, \ldots, a_{n-1}$ are all integers in $\{ 0, \ldots, 9 \}$ - that is, the ordinary decimal expansion of $A$.   Then you can write A followed by its reversal as

$$ 10^n (10^{n-1} a_{n-1} + 10^{n-2} a_{n-2} + \cdots + 10^0 a_0) + (10^{n-1} a_0 + 10^{n-2} a_1 + \cdots + 10^0 a_{n-1})$$

and now let's rearrange this so that the terms with the same $a_i$ are together.  It equals

$$ a_{n-1} (10^{2n-1} + 10^0) + a_{n-2} (10^{2n-2} + 10^1) + \cdots + a_0 (10^n + 10^{n-1}). $$

Each factor of the form $10^k + 10^l$, where $k-l$ is odd, is divisible by 11.  To see this you can factor

$$10^k + 10^l = 10^l (10^{k-l} + 1) = 10^l (10 + 1) (10^{k-l-1} - 10^{k-l-2} + \cdots + 1), $$
where the signs in the last factor are alternating.  This is just the well-known rule for factoring sums of $n$th powers

$$(a+b)^n = (a+b) (a^{n-1} - a^{n-2} b + a^{n-3} b^2 - \cdots - a b^{n-2} + b^{n-1}), $$

which applies when $n$ is odd.

So our number is a sum of integer multiples of 11, and is therefore divisible by 11.

Comment: And I will gladly push you over the 10k mark for this answer. :)

Comment: This is clearer if one exploits the *polynomial form* of radix notation - see my answer.

Answer (score 12):

**Hint** $\ $ If in radix $b,\,$ we have  $\,n = f(b) = f_0\! + f_1 b  +\,\cdots+ f_n b^n,\,$ then reversing the digits of $\,n\,$ yields the integer  $\,\bar n = \bar f(b)\,$ for $\,\bar f(b) = b^n f(b^{-1})$ the reversed polynomial.  Appending  yields

$$ {\rm mod}\,\ b\!+\!1\!:\,\ b\equiv -1\,\Rightarrow\,  b^{n+1} f(b) + b^n f(b^{-1})\,\equiv\, (-1)^n f(-1)(-1 + 1)\,\equiv\, 0\qquad $$

Answer (score 10):

Every number obtained by this construction is divisible by $11$. Here is a simple test for divisibility by $11$: if the number is $a_r\cdots a_0$, it is divisible by $11$ iff $\sum_{i=0}^r (-1)^ia_i = 0$. This follows from the fact that $10^{2i+1}=-1\bmod{11}$ and $10^{2i} = 1\bmod{11}$. Thus, $a_r\cdots a_0 = \sum 10^ia_i = \sum (-1)^i a_i\bmod{11}$.

Now, since every digit of the number you construct appear in an odd and an even place, the whole number is divisible by $11$.

Comment: Your answer is a bit more rigorous than mine.

Comment: This is the answer I would have given

Answer (score 1):

Another way to realize this is to break it down as far as we can, and consider a basic "building block": any number of the form $$1\underset{2n}{\underbrace{0...0}}1 - 11= \underset{2n}{\underbrace{9...9}}0$$
if we divide the number on the right hand side with 11, we get an integer with pattern of $n$ "09"s.

This gives some intuition why any position of digits of a palindromic number should be divisible by 11. What is left is to "move" the pieces into place and multiply them with the corresponding digit. The first one is a multiplication with a $10^k$ which does not destroy divisibility and neither does the second. Also we need that addition of numbers divisible preserve divisibility, and it does!